# Is there StackOverflow flavored markdown for Thunderbird?

Tags: thunderbird, text-formatting, markdown

Currently I am using Thunderbird quite frequently to send and receive code blocks, sometimes with debug information. Is there StackOverflow flavored markdown for Thunderbird?

Comment: You would need to write an add-on.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/121981/stackoverflow-official-wmd-editor

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since Stack Overflow uses [Markdown](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/) for parsing, you can simply write in Markdown and then format your e-mails with a Markdown-to-HTML parser.

One of these is [Markdown Here](https://github.com/adam-p/markdown-here), which with the click of a button turns your Markdown-formatted source into shiny rich text, even with syntax highlighting.

[image]

It's available as a [Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/elifhakcjgalahccnjkneoccemfahfoa), and [Firefox / Thunderbird add-on](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/markdown-here/), which you would use. The developer is very supportive when it comes to bug fixes and feature request, and I've seen him here on Stack Exchange as well.

---

To write the actual Markdown, I'm not aware of any Thunderbird add-ons that'd get you the Stack Exchange keybindings, but you can use an editor like the [online-markdown-editor](http://homepage.univie.ac.at/werner.robitza/markdown/) I forked from the official Stack Exchange tool and [hosted on GitHub](https://github.com/slhck/online-markdown-editor). It supports the same keybindings.